# What chords rule can I use on the piano for composing in C minor key?

Tags: theory

If I'm composing music in C minor, so all the chords should be in minor ? Example Cm, Dm, D#m, Fm, G minor, G# minor, A#(Bb) minor. Kindly advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since C minor is the relative minor of Eb major, those seven from that key are a good start point: Eb, Fm, Gm, Ab, Bb, Cm and Do. Because it's minor, you may well feel the need to use the dominant of G maj rather than Gm.

It's entirely possible that any or all of those chords could be extended, or altered, as in G becomes G7, G9, G+, etc.

If the piece modulates, then new chords come into play, associated with the new 'key'.
Other chords are available, too, and will generally depend on what notes they accompany. So, if in a bar with, say, C and Eb only, F7, Co will also fit. Whether they sound good or not is in the ear of the beholder.

Just noticed you ask about 'rule'. Not sure what you mean by that.